# Drop down menu for the graph

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, drop-down-menu, plotly

I am new to python and I'm trying to make a drop down menu for this graph that shows temperatures at different times of day.The datas are imported from a csv file . Below is the code:

```
import csv

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
 
x=[]
 
y=[] 

z=[]
 
w=[] 

class grafice_statice():

    def run(self):
        with open('temperatura.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
            date = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in date:
                try:
                    y.append(float(row[0]))
                    z.append(float(row[1]))
                    w.append(float(row[2]))
                    x.append(row[3])
                except Exception as e:
                    pass

        
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(x,z, color='g', linestyle='dotted', marker='o', label='Temp 2(°C)!')
        plt.plot(x,y, color='m', linestyle='solid', marker='P', label='Temp 1(°C)!')
        plt.plot(x,w, color='r', linestyle='dashdot', marker='D', label='Temp 3(°C)!')

        plt.xlabel('Timpul')
        plt.ylabel('Temperatura(°C)')
        plt.title('Temperatura in functie de timp', fontsize = 18)
        plt.legend()

        plt.xticks([0,50,99])
        plt.ylim((-5,5))
        plt.show()
             
    grafice_stat=grafice_statice()
    grafice_stat.run()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to set up a dropdown menu to let the user choose which temperature plot to display. One way to do this is to use the ipywidgets `Dropdown` function. More info about it can be found [here](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html).

You can find an example below, where I created 3 random temperature vectors (since I didn't have access to your data). They are stored in the list `temp`. I then let the user choose which temperature vector to plot through the dropdown menu with the line `dropdown=widgets.Dropdown(options=[('Temp1', 0), ('Temp2', 1), ('Temp3', 2)],value=0,description='Temp')`. Once the user chooses, it automatically update the figure through the `on_change(change)` function.

So, overall the code looks like that:

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

def t_temp(N_points):
  temp_min=-20
  temp_max=40
  temp=np.random.choice(np.arange(temp_min,temp_max),size=N_points)
  return temp 

colors=['tab:blue','tab:orange','tab:green']
N_points=100
t=1+np.arange(N_points)
N_temp_types=3
temp=[]
[temp.append(t_temp(N_points)) for i in range(N_temp_types)]

dropdown=widgets.Dropdown(options=[('Temp1', 0), ('Temp2', 1), ('Temp3', 2)],value=0,description='Temp')
plt.plot(t,temp[int(dropdown.value)],lw=2,color=colors[int(dropdown.value)],label='Temp '+ str(int(dropdown.value)+1))
plt.legend()

def on_change(change):
    if change['type'] == 'change' and change['name'] == 'value':
        clear_output()
        display(dropdown)
        plt.plot(t,temp[int(dropdown.value)],lw=2,color=colors[int(dropdown.value)],label='Temp '+ str(int(dropdown.value)+1))
        plt.legend()
dropdown.observe(on_change)

display(dropdown)
```

And the output gives:

When "Temp1" is selected:

[image]

When "Temp2" is selected:

[image]